# Prove those inequalities are true

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, absolute-value

I want to prove that those inequalities are true for $a, b ∈ R$:
$$ |a + b| ≤ |a| + |b| $$
$$ ||a| − |b|| ≤ |a − b| $$
$$ |a − b| ≤ |a − c| + |c − b| $$

Now I can see that they are true, and I could argue it with words, but how would you prove it on paper using mathematic notation?

Comment: This very much depends on what you are already given. Could you provide us with some background on what you already know and what you tried so far?

Comment: Think about what the absolute value of something means. It may help to consider that $|x|=\max\{x,-x\}$.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner what I would try is take every case possible - a positive, b positive | a negative, b negative | a positive, b negative | a negative, b positive. Now I would show what it would look like after getting rid of the abs() and show that the statement is true for all cases.

Comment: Also, the second two can be proven using the first (see if you can do this), so then all you need to do is prove the first!

Comment: @Mykybo that is a good idea.

Comment: @J.Cork though I am not sure how I would use the first equation to prove the other two?

Comment: The idea of case distinction is right, but you should choose your cases so that in each case you can evaluate the term $|x-y|$ using whatever definition of $|\cdot|$ you’re using. And as J.Cork already pointed out the last two equations follow from the first by some playing around.

Comment: We have a problem.  What if $a,b$ is complex?!

Comment: @Mykybo In both cases, try applying the first inequality to things such as "$|a|=|a-b+b|$" etc

Comment: They are inequalities, not equations.

Comment: @user236182 you are right, corrected

Comment: You can define $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$.  Try squaring both sides.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig That is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

$$|x|=x$$$$x\ge0$$$$|y|=-y$$$$y<0$$

Try using that.  Treat every case for $x$, the stuff inside the absolute values, individually until you find the answer.

An idea, noted in the comments by N. F. Taussig, is as follows:

$$|a|=+\sqrt{a^2}$$

So we have the following (easiest to use an equal sign):

$$\sqrt{(a+b)^2}=|a+b|=\sqrt{a^2}+\sqrt{b^2}$$

$$(a+b)^2=(\sqrt{a^2}+\sqrt{b^2})^2$$

$$a^2+2ab+b^2=a^2+2\sqrt{a^2b^2}+b^2$$

$$2ab=2\sqrt{a^2b^2}$$

We have the following scenarios, $a,b\ge0$, then we have:

$$2ab=2ab$$

If we have $a,b<0$, then we have:

$$2(-a)(-b)=2ab$$

If we have $a$ **or** $b$ $<0$, then we have:

$$2(-a)b=2a(-b)<0<2\sqrt{a^2(-b)^2}=2\sqrt{(-a)^2b^2}=2\sqrt{a^2b^2}=2ab$$

Using the $<0<$ in the middle helps define what is happening.

The same would have happened if had used the definition $|x|=x,x\ge0$ and $|x|=-x,x<0$.

Essentially, instead of proving it with words, we break it in to different scenarios describing when the values will be positive or negative by simply using $x\ge0$ or $x<0$.

Comment: This problem was posed for real numbers, however it does still hold for complex numbers. In fact for any metric-vector-space, where $|x|=d(x,0)$, these inequalities must hold.